# bootstrap-theme.css.map not generated by Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

When Web Essentials minifies css files, it does not generate the map files.
Do I miss any special settings?

Here's my `WebEssentials-Settings.json`:

```
{
  "BrowserLink": {
    "CssIgnorePatterns": "bootstrap*; reset.css; normalize.css; jquery*; toastr*; foundation*; animate*; inuit*; elements*; ratchet*; hint*; flat-ui*; 960*; skeleton*",
    "EnableMenu": true,
    "EnablePixelPushing": true,
    "ShowMenu": true
  },
  "CodeGen": {
    "CamelCasePropertyNames": true,
    "CamelCaseTypeNames": false
  },
  "CoffeeScript": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message",
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "WrapClosure": true
  },
  "Css": {
    "AdjustRelativePaths": true,
    "AutoMinify": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "ShowBrowserTooltip": true,
    "ShowInitialInherit": false,
    "ShowUnsupported": true,
    "SyncVendorValues": true,
    "ValidateEmbedImages": true,
    "ValidateOverQualifiedSelector": true,
    "ValidateStarSelector": true,
    "ValidateVendorSpecifics": true,
    "ValidateZeroUnit": true,
    "ValidationLocation": "Messages"
  },
  "General": {
    "AllMessagesToOutputWindow": false,
    "KeepImportantComments": true,
    "SvgPreviewPane": true
  },
  "Html": {
    "AutoMinify": false,
    "EnableAngularValidation": true,
    "EnableEnterFormat": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "ImageDropFormats": [
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" />",
        "Name": "Simple Image Tag"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<div><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></div>",
        "Name": "Enclosed in Div"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<li id=\"item_{1}\"><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></li>",
        "Name": "Enclosed as List Item"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<div style=\"background-image=url('{0}')\"></div>",
        "Name": "Inline CSS"
      }
    ]
  },
  "JavaScript": {
    "AutoMinify": true,
    "BlockCommentCompletion": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message"
  },
  "Less": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  },
  "Markdown": {
    "AutoHyperlink": false,
    "AutoNewLines": false,
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EncodeProblemUrlCharacters": false,
    "GenerateXHTML": true,
    "LinkEmails": false,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "StrictBoldItalic": false
  },
  "Scss": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  },
  "SweetJs": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  },
  "TypeScript": {
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message",
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  }
}
```